# AWK- reading an excel file(CSV) and making another

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am using "awk" command to read my csv file, I want to use it with a condition, if the condition is valid i want to take the "row" not with all the columns and write it in another csv file.

For example:

the CSV File:

***fname***    ***lname***    ***id***    ***address***    ***street***    ***phone***   ***telephone***

***row1***:myfname mylname  123  serlanka  j12street  05666355 02365410

***row2***...

**row3**...

***the condition***: if the row have an ***id*** "123" -> then i want just ***fname***, ***lname*** and ***id*** columns in the new csv.

I've used awk command in my code.

***code***:

```
           zcat "$FileName" | awk -F'\t' '(($4 >=400) && ($4 <=599)) {Str="HTTP Error:  " $4;print Str >> "New.csv"}'
```

How can I write the row or some information from the same row.

Thanks.

Comment: Your example is not comma separated (as one would expect from a CSV file), but just has spaces. Please confirm the field delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less add this to the end of your script:

```
$3 ~ /123/ {print $1,$2,$3 >> "New.csv"}
```

Comment: i have a problem, i'v opened the csv file(the result) in exel,the rows was copied in one coulmn.

for ex: col1:fname col2:lname col3:id

result : col1: fname lname id !!!!!!

thanks

Comment: By default OFS (output field separator) is space. I assume Excel didn't recognize that as the CVS delimiter. Set the OFS to some more appropriate delimiter: `awk -OFS=";" ...`

Comment: Sorry, my bad: `awk -v OFS=";" ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the field delimiter is just spaces:

```
awk '$3 == "123" {print $1,$2,$3}'
```

or this if the field delimiter is a `,`

```
awk -F, '$3 == "123" {print $1,$2,$3}'
```